# Is it possible to detect eyes only without detecting the face?

Tags: python, image-processing, haar-classifier

I have been studying in Haar-cascade. I have been following tutorial whicg detect faces and then detect eyes. From I found online, mostly it will be face detected first then eyes. Is it not possible to detect eyes only?

This is my code for detect faces and eyes.

```
import cv2
import numpy

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        rol_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        rol_color = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.5,5)
        if eyes is None:
            print ("Can't find")
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.imwrite('FaceFileName.jpg', img)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(30) % 0xFF
if k == 27:
    break;
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As you can see I use cascade for detect face first and then eyes. I also tried remove face cascade, only eyes cascade remained. The result is eyes can't be found. Can haar-cascade detect eyes only? Is it necessary to detect face first then eyes?

Comment: the question is why do you want to skip detecting the face? eyes are usually on a face ;)

Comment: I know that it's always on the face LOL. However, I'd like to know if you only take a partial picture of your face. For example, just eyes and nose. How to detect eyes if there is a case like that? @Piglet